# Umbraco Partial Views with meta-tags

Tags: asp.net, umbraco, partial-views

Let's suppose I have a page with ten products. When I click a button on one of the products it opens a pop-up (partial view) which has some share buttons. When I click 'Share on Facebook' it needs to have the correct meta-tags (title of the product, description of the product and image of the product).

Is this possible and if so, how?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  I assume you link to the 10 products page instead of the pop-up. and you don't have a detail page for the product to link to? put some url parameter in the share link to produce the right http://ogp.me/ and meta tags dynamicaly in your 10 products page.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, check my answer on how I managed to do it if you're interested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing a view and a page from umbraco on which it renders the view from the controller. It adds the correct meta-tags, dynamically.
The user clicks share and that's it, I just serve facebook's crawler a product page which the user won't see. Then when someone clicks the shared url from facebook it will get a redirect to my desired URL. 
Previously tried with javascript and ajax, or even alter the master template tags from the controller and even checking if facebook's crawler gets on the website, only the last one worked partially but yuck...